# Should i store images in SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to store 100 images and sounds files in SQLite. Is it possible to store this data?

How many MB of data can be stored in SQLite?

Regards

Aswan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be best to store the files in the filesystem or memory card, then reference to them in the SQLite database, with columns such as `_id` and `fileLocation`.

Comment: rather than sd card if you have any example pl help me

Answer (score 2):

I would store the files as - well - files. If you store them in SQLite then they need to fit in memory.